# Can't printf an integer in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, printf

I'm really new to c++. I opened a new project and I was trying to start and print using printf.
When I'm printing strings it works great but, when I try to print integers, it causes an error.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and using a Windows 10 computer.
[error and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v7Lp.png)

This is the simple code i'm trying to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf(i);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", i);` - and remove `return 0;`

Comment: **sidenote** :: question is tagged with C++ and `stdio.h` is not a C++ header. Please, use the c++ header files and functions.

Comment: Ted is correct, however you should check out the [reference sheet](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for more on how printf works, so that you can understand how to do more than just decimals!

Comment: @alteredinstance Prefer this site: [ref sheet @ cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: @dorKKnight - You interpretation is over-simplistic.  All C++ standards explicitly support a set of C headers as part of the C++ standard library, including `<stdio.h>`, for reasons of backward compatibility although their usage is deprecated.

Comment: Please note that once execution hits a return the function is done executing.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` can't print `int` (or `size_t`) like that. Instead, give it the correct specifier (`%d` for `int` and `%zu` for `size_t`):

```
int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%zu", i);
    }
    return 0; // not needed for main - default is 0
}
```

If you're interested in what `printf` can print and how to do that, you can find a documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Wow, I completely oversaw that. Thanks!

Comment: The `return 0` is optional for `int main` for newer versions, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged and stated that you're using `C++` (not `C`), so try using the far nicer/easier output functions provided by streams:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the other answer and comments are perfectly fine, if you insist on using `printf`!

Comment: `std::endl` is rarely required, just use `'\n'`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I agree - but it's a matter of choice/preference/compatibility.

Comment: Choosing `endl` is a bad choice, as it also flushes the buffer, which is really unneeded.